# Class.forName + ExceptionInInitializerError + static initialization + weird Array init

Tags: java, java.lang.class

I recently "inherited" a project and tried to get an instance of a service running locally. I encountered - and fixed - some problems with code similar to...

```java
class A {
   // ...
   public void doSomething() {
      // ...
      Class foo = Class.forName("fully.qualified.package.B"); 
      // ...  
   }
   // ...
}

class B {
    static String[] bar = (String[])Arrays.asList("Something").toArray();
    //...
}
```

When Class A.doSomething() was run, an `ExceptionInInitializerError` was thrown. This error has something to do with initializing Class B (static init, no instantiation!!).

**FYI >** Fixing this Problem can be done in two ways...

- **Class A**, use `Class.forName("fully.qualified.package.B", false, this.getClass().getRuntime());` - where the second parameter `false` does not initialize the class.
- **Class B**, using a normal array init `static String[] bar = { "Something" };`.

**What I am interested in is...**

Why would the somewhat overengineered initialization via `(String[]) Arrays.asList(...).toArray()` cause such an error?

---

**Solution/Edit:** It has nothing to do with static initialization, the array init is plain wrong, see below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(String[])Arrays.asList("Something").toArray();` is going to fail at runtime: it's not returning a `String[]`, it's returning an `Object[]`. `Object[]` and `String[]` are reifiable types, so it's a checked cast, and because an `Object[]` is not a `String[]`, it fails.

Use `Arrays.asList("Something").toArray(new String[0])`; or just `new String[]{"Something"}`.

Comment: You are right, didn't occur to me to question the cast, focussed only on the static init. Project is live and running and I assumed this would work. As written in my question, FYA - initializing the array via `{"..."}` solves the problem. Thanks for opening my eyes :-)